# iOS 14 Widget fails signing

Tags: ios, xcode, widgetkit

I hava a NFC app which uses `com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotConfiguration` and `com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats` entitlements.

My bundle identifier for the widget is `xx.yyyy.zzzzzz.NFCWidgetiOS14` where `xx.yyyy.zzzzzz` is the apps identifer.

Xcode 12 Beta 6 fails to sign the widget and I don't know why. I have checked appstoreconnect identifiers section but I could not find anything relating to widgets. My old pre iOS 14 widget widget works just fine.

Am I missing something out?

[image: Image of Xcode failing signing widget for iOS 14]

Comment: I have had a similar problem and I solved by first, remove "Automatically manage signing" from "Signin & Capabilities" then from "Build Setting" set manually "Code Signin Identity"

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing me in that direction. However it was something else. See my answer @MartinoBonfiglioli

Comment: I already have manual code signing, 2 profiles. But when building got error, that host app is signed, but Embedded Binary Signing Certificate: Not Code Signed
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Martinos comment to the build settings I managed to fix it. The problem was that the widget target had the apps entitlement file linked under `WidgetTarget -> Build Settings -> Code Signing Entitlements` which is clearly not needed for the widget. After I deleted the entitlement there the signing worked.